# Which Star Trek episodes were based on spec scripts?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

It recently came to my attention that some Star Trek episodes for various series were based on spec scripts, essentially unsolicited (fan) submissions. (And as the cliche goes, that blew my mind)

For example, TNG episode [Yesterday's Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Enterprise_%28episode%29) (the script was intensely modified, but still).

Is there a list of all spec script episodes (that came in from open submissions) for all Star Trek series?

Comment: A list you say?

Comment: @GorchestopherH It could be huge, but should be finite - there is no currently airing Star Trek series.

Comment: @GorchestopherH Y'know, unless you find a reference, [as shown in the question](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Enterprise_(episode)#Story_development).  (`The original idea for "Yesterday's Enterprise" was generated by Trent Christopher Ganino and submitted to Paramount on 15 April 1989, as a spec script submitted through the open submissions policy introduced by Michael Piller in that year.`)  This is not a bad list question.

Comment: TOS, in common with most series, didn't even open script submissions that didn't come through an agent.

Comment: You could probably parse through wikipedia and Memory Alpha to get a large number.  "The Bonding" was Ron D. Moore's first script, written on spec.  It's also awful.

Comment: @GorchestopherH you're right. I forgot. Despite Izkata's vote. I'm going to let the question get closed, I guess. I was really excited by the discovery though.

Comment: @jonnyflash Thanks for the suggestion. Chances not all are declared as such in Memory Alpha. "The Bonding" article makes no mention of it in those words.

Comment: @GorchestopherH There are 3 votes to close currently, one of which is actually mine. I'm letting the community decide.

Comment: @sfhq_sf I don't think this is [tag:episode-identification], since it's asking for a list rather than a specific episode.

Answer (score 7):

**There have been at least 6**

According to this article [Write for Star Trek](http://www.wired.com/1996/01/trek-script/) written in 1996 there have been 4 spec scripts accepted for production;

- "The Bonding"  Ron Moore
- "Measure of a Man"  Melinda Snodgrass
- "The Offspring"  Rene Echevarria
- "Tin Man"  Dennis Bailey and David Bishoff

Eric Stillwell came up with the story for "Yesterday's Enterprise" for TNG and also "Prime Factors" for Voyager.

Robert Hewitt Wolfe’s first big break was selling the script “A Fistful of Datas” but it's not clear if it was really a 'spec script' or if he was working for Paramount in some capacity at the time.